# Problem with my footer after changing WooCommerce Products Sorting

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic

Recently I needed to change the products sorting to see the in-stock products first and the out of stock products after that, I did that with a snippet in my functions.php file:

```
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{

 public function __construct()
 {
  // Check if WooCommerce is active
  if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
   add_filter('posts_clauses', array($this, 'order_by_stock_status'), 2000);
  }
 }

 public function order_by_stock_status($posts_clauses)
 {
  global $wpdb;
  // only change query on WooCommerce loops
  if (is_woocommerce() && (is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag())) {
   $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
   $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
   $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
  }
  return $posts_clauses;
 }
}

new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```

Now my footer is not visible in Product Categories, Search, Shop Page, and Product Tag, and I have no idea what is going on :D website URL is: https://lotuslaptop.com

I appreciate any answers :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs probably because you don't check for the post type when overriding the post clauses.

Your filter callback needs a second parameter which is a `WP_Query` instance, and then use it to check if the `post_type` is what you need. If you don't check for that, you'll be overriding every single database query for any type of posts your website does on those WooCommerce pages.

Please try using this edited code, and check my comments in it:

```php
class iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Check if WooCommerce is active
        if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
            // Added the fourth parameter 2 for the number of parameters to pass to the callback method
            add_filter( 'posts_clauses', [ $this, 'order_by_stock_status' ], 2000, 2 );
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string[]  $posts_clauses
     * @param \WP_Query $query
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function order_by_stock_status( $posts_clauses, $query )
    {
        // Bail early if the post_type is not what we need
        if ( $query->get( 'post_type' ) !== 'product' ) {
            return $posts_clauses;
        }

        global $wpdb;
        // only change query on WooCommerce loops
        if ( is_woocommerce() && ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) ) {
            $posts_clauses['join'] .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta istockstatus ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = istockstatus.post_id) ";
            $posts_clauses['orderby'] = " istockstatus.meta_value ASC, " . $posts_clauses['orderby'];
            $posts_clauses['where'] = " AND istockstatus.meta_key = '_stock_status' AND istockstatus.meta_value <> '' " . $posts_clauses['where'];
        }

        return $posts_clauses;
    }
}

new iWC_Orderby_Stock_Status;
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem has been solved and the footer is back.